# "ProtocolException: problem parsing majorVersion=null as int" Android Q Beta 3

Tags: android, protocolexception, android-10.0

I'm getting this exception in my app, after trying it on Android Q Beta 3. Looks like I'm missing `majorVersion` parameter... but I haven't found it in the documentation. Does anyone faced this issue?

```
java.net.ProtocolException: problem parsing majorVersion=null as int
    at com.android.internal.util.XmlUtils.readIntAttribute(XmlUtils.java:1622)
    at com.android.server.usage.UsageStatsXmlV1.read(UsageStatsXmlV1.java:391)
    at com.android.server.usage.UsageStatsXml.read(UsageStatsXml.java:48)
    at com.android.server.usage.UsageStatsDatabase.readLocked(UsageStatsDatabase.java:992)
    at com.android.server.usage.UsageStatsDatabase.readLocked(UsageStatsDatabase.java:862)
    at com.android.server.usage.UsageStatsDatabase.continueUpgradeLocked(UsageStatsDatabase.java:500)
    at com.android.server.usage.UsageStatsDatabase.checkVersionAndBuildLocked(UsageStatsDatabase.java:369)
    at com.android.server.usage.UsageStatsDatabase.init(UsageStatsDatabase.java:164)
    at com.android.server.usage.UserUsageStatsService.init(UserUsageStatsService.java:108)
    at com.android.server.usage.UsageStatsService.getUserDataAndInitializeIfNeededLocked(UsageStatsService.java:399)
    at com.android.server.usage.UsageStatsService.onStart(UsageStatsService.java:249)
    at com.android.server.SystemServiceManager.startService(SystemServiceManager.java:129)
    at com.android.server.SystemServiceManager.startService(SystemServiceManager.java:116)
    at com.android.server.SystemServer.startCoreServices(SystemServer.java:805)
    at com.android.server.SystemServer.run(SystemServer.java:511)
    at com.android.server.SystemServer.main(SystemServer.java:349)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:903)
```

also another similar exception

```
    java.net.ProtocolException: problem parsing minorVersion=null as int
    at com.android.internal.util.XmlUtils.readIntAttribute(XmlUtils.java:1622)
    at com.android.server.usage.UsageStatsXmlV1.read(UsageStatsXmlV1.java:397)
    at com.android.server.usage.UsageStatsXml.read(UsageStatsXml.java:48)
    at com.android.server.usage.UsageStatsDatabase.readLocked(UsageStatsDatabase.java:992)
    at com.android.server.usage.UsageStatsDatabase.readLocked(UsageStatsDatabase.java:862)
    at com.android.server.usage.UsageStatsDatabase.continueUpgradeLocked(UsageStatsDatabase.java:500)
    at com.android.server.usage.UsageStatsDatabase.checkVersionAndBuildLocked(UsageStatsDatabase.java:369)
    at com.android.server.usage.UsageStatsDatabase.init(UsageStatsDatabase.java:164)
    at com.android.server.usage.UserUsageStatsService.init(UserUsageStatsService.java:108)
    at com.android.server.usage.UsageStatsService.getUserDataAndInitializeIfNeededLocked(UsageStatsService.java:399)
    at com.android.server.usage.UsageStatsService.onStart(UsageStatsService.java:249)
    at com.android.server.SystemServiceManager.startService(SystemServiceManager.java:129)
    at com.android.server.SystemServiceManager.startService(SystemServiceManager.java:116)
    at com.android.server.SystemServer.startCoreServices(SystemServer.java:805)
    at com.android.server.SystemServer.run(SystemServer.java:511)
    at com.android.server.SystemServer.main(SystemServer.java:349)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:903)
```

Comment: What specifically are you doing that is triggering these exceptions? The stack traces just show system classes.

Comment: I wish I knew... I saw these logs while was just using app during Android Q testing to see if there were any errors.

Comment: So... are you sure that they are from your app?